# Manual Login flow with Facebook in Mac os App

Tags: objective-c

I am learning mac app development and i want to implement login with Facebook in my mac OS app. But i try to find SDK of Facebook in developer account but did not got any SDK for mac. I read somewhere that we can implement manually login flow using Facebook graph API but i don't know how to implement. Any one did Facebook login for mac desktop app than please suggest me how to implement.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Manually Build a Login Flow
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow?locale=en_US

Anyone implemented this approach under macOS?